# React onClick not triggering

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project. I have a lot of HTML/JSX content, so I'll try to resume the code to the issue.

I have a top menu component where I have my logout button.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

...

function TopMenu(props) {
  // initial settings and logout method
  const [properties, dispatchProperties] = useReducer(propertyReducer, { properties: []});
  const [totalTenants, setTotalTenants] = useState(0);
  const [totalApplicants, setTotalApplicants] = useState(0);
  const [totalWorkOrders, setTotalWorkOrders] = useState(0);
  const [selectedPropName, setSelectedPropName] = useState("");

  const user = props.user;
  const userFulName = `${user.userFName} ${user.userLName}`;
  const userLevel = user.userLevel;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setTotalTenants(await tenantsApi.getTotalTenants(user.propertyID));
      setTotalApplicants(await applicantsApi.getTotalApplicants(user.propertyID));
      setTotalWorkOrders(await wkApi.getTotalWK(user.propertyID));

      const ps = [
        {id: 1, name: "Prop1"},
        {id: 2, name: "Prop2"},
        {id: 3, name: "Prop3"},
        {id: 4, name: "Prop4"},
        {id: 5, name: "Prop5"}
      ];
      dispatchProperties({ type: actionTypes.GET_PROPERTIES, payload: ps});
      for(const p of ps) {
        if(p.id === user.propertyID) {
          setSelectedPropName(p.name);
          break;
        }
      }
    })();
  }, [user.propertyID]);

  const onLogOut = () => {
    console.log('here');
    removeUserSession();
    props.updLogged(false);
  }

  return (
    ...
    ...
    <div className="widget-content-right mr-2">
      <button className="btn-pill btn-shadow btn-shine btn btn-focus" onClick={() => onLogOut()}>Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TopMenu;
```

When I click on the Logout, nothing happens. Not even the console.log('here') displays. Am I binding it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a possibility that your component gets stuck rerendering in the useEffect? If the dispatchProperties triggers a rerender because of the useReducer

Comment: The binding is correct, the issue must be on your useEffect

Comment: Makes sense. How could I check it?

Comment: You could try and place a breakpoint in the useEffect function while debugging to see if you continue hitting it

Comment: I added a console.log there (useEffect) and it is called just one time. It's odd I forced a ```sessionStorage.removeItem('user')``` and reload my application. Now, the button works. Could it be a cache issue?

Comment: Then, a few minutes later, it stopped working again